# create variable names with specific order in r

Tags: r, dplyr, paste

I want to get some variable names with specific order, like this

***I0.n, I0.man, I0.woman, I0.low65, I0.up65***

***I1.n, I1.man, I1.woman, I1.low65, I1.up65***

***... ... ...***

***I99.n, I99.man, I99.woman, I99.low65, I99.up65***

I tried a way but failed

```
num <- sprintf('%02d',0:99)
index <- c('n', 'man', 'woman', 'low65', 'up65')
vars <- paste0('I', num, '.', index)
```

Is there a efficent way to create the variable names with specific order?

Any help will be highly appreciated !

Comment: You probably want `with(expand.grid(index=index, num=num), paste0('I', num, '.', index))`.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks a lot, that's what I need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by `@MrFlick`, a simple and compact way to achieve this is to use the following code:

```
data <- with(expand.grid(index=index, num=num), paste0('I', num, '.', index))

> data
[1] "I00.n"     "I00.man"   "I00.woman" "I00.low65" "I00.up65"  "I01.n"     "I01.man"   "I01.woman"
[9] "I01.low65" "I01.up65"  "I02.n"     "I02.man"   "I02.woman" "I02.low65" "I02.up65"  "I03.n"
...
[497] "I99.man"   "I99.woman" "I99.low65" "I99.up65"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It really helps me! Thank you very much.